# how do i make my modal jquery load when page finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, pageload

I'm really new to javascript and jquery. I'm trying to open this modal when the page loads but it's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My PopUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>

<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>   



<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also in the instructions says that I can add a fade but when I put the script nothing happens. This is the script for fade transitions.

```
$("#fade").modal({
  fadeDuration: 100
});
```

Thank you.

Guide: https://jquerymodal.com/

Comment: Where is `#fade` coming from ? You have some `id` selector issue here.

Comment: Here is a working demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/wc9t3myL/

Comment: I have another question, what if I want to show it only the first time the user enters the web page? @AlwaysHelping

Comment: You have check how that is accessing the web page is the use getting logged in or just a public user. It’s it’s public user then there is a lot of work that you need to do to set browser cookies and etc. if you want to show modal once to just logged in users you have save some data in your database to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `$("#ex1").modal({ fadeDuration: 100 });` where `#ex1` is the id selector of your model

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My PopUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>

<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>   



<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#ex1").modal({
  fadeDuration: 100
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ex1').modal({fadeDuration: 100})
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My PopUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>

<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>   



<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

By using `$(document).ready()` you are telling js to wait until the page is loaded and then execute you code which loads your modal.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have another question, what if I want to show it only the first time the user enters to the web page?

Comment: @Niallkalipe For that you'll need the client to remember that it's been before so you'll need to save a cookie and check before launching the modal